# Create ActiveX checkbox in specific cell

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

In my Sheet 1, Column A has some values and I need to create a Active X checkbox for all the values in Sheet 2 in a specific cell. First I need to check whether Active X checkbox is there for the value or not, If its not there, I need to create. I already tried the below code, But its creating the duplicate checkboxes.

```
Sub Addcheckbox()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim rr As Integer
Dim tf As Boolean
Dim shpTemp As Shape

Set rng = Range("A1:A8")
Set Destrng = Range("A2:A9")
rr = 2
For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A8")
    If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
     With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", _
        Left:=51.75, Top:=183, Width:=120, Height:=19.5)
        .Object.Caption = cell.Value
    End With
    End If
rr = rr + 1
Next cell
End Sub
```

How to check whether ActiveX checkbox already present in the sheet or not with Caption name

i tried this code for checking the checkboxes.. But its not working..

```
Function shapeExists(ByRef shapename As String) As Boolean

    shapeExists = False
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If sh.name = shapename Then
            shapeExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next sh


End Function
```

Comment: Where are you checking if the textbox exists or now?

Comment: In Sheet 2. I need to check Active X check box is there or not with the caption name I pass..  For Ex, for value 'A', I need to check the checkbox with the caption name 'A' exists or not..if its not there, I need to create a new @SiddharthRout

Comment: I know that but where are you checking if it exists or not. I can give you the code but I want you to try it first

Comment: ok.. I updated my post.. I tried writing a function for checking the checkboxes.. But its not working. I am just started with learning VBA..@SiddharthRout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveX Checkboxes are `OleObjects`. Is this what you are trying?

Also you need to specify the correct `.Top` else they will be created at the same place. See how I used `Top:=cell.Top`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim rr As Integer
    Dim tf As Boolean
    Dim shpTemp As Shape

    Set rng = Range("A1:A8")
    Set Destrng = Range("A2:A9")

    rr = 2

    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A8")
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            If Not CBExists(cell.Value) Then '<~~ Check if the checkbox exists
                With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", _
                        Left:=51.75, Top:=cell.Top, Width:=120, Height:=19.5)
                        .Object.Caption = cell.Value
                End With
            End If
        End If
        rr = rr + 1
    Next cell
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if the checkbox exists
Function CBExists(s As String) As Boolean
    Dim oleObj As OLEObject
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Count
        If s = Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects(i).Object.Caption Then
            CBExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Worked Thanks.. the check boxes are created vertically.. Is there a way to create these horizontally ? @Siddharth Rout

Comment: It is created vertically because of `Top:=cell.Top`. To create horz, you need to change `Left:=` ;) try it

Comment: If I changed to `Left:=cell.Left` as you told, checkboxes are creating in the same place.. @Siddharth Rout

Comment: Correct. So what do you think you should do? ;) I can give you the answer but imagine how will you feel once you find it yourself? Hint: What if you had a variable which calculates the left before placing the textbox?

Comment: There is function called `IncrementLeft`. 

For ex: `ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox8").IncrementLeft 218.25` 

correct approach ? @Siddharth Rout

Comment: Nope :) Like I said, use a variable and increment the variable. So for example, the first time, The `Left:=51.75`. Next it will be `51.75 + Checkbox.Width + Some buffer` and next it will be `51.75 + Checkbox.Width + CheckBOx Width + Some buffer` and so on ;)